# Where for loop is executed.. driver node or execter nodes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

for ex: we are trying to read data from oracle from multiple tables using for loop... where for loop is executing line by line.. either driver node or executers nodes..

for eg.. variables get created... where they saved driver node or executer nodes

I am bit new to spark.. could you please explain

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop is executed by the driver. The data is read by the executors. But as the `for` loop is on the driver, the tables will be read sequentially. If you want to read them in parallel, you need to submit the jobs from different threads. Look at multithreading in python.

The variables in your code are created by the driver. It will send to the nodes the tasks that they need to perform, packed with a copy of the needed variables. If you want to avoid having a copy of each variable for each task, you can use broadcasting to have only a copy of each variable for each node (which contains multiple executors). This is useful for large read-only variables.